# How To Join 3 Tables In Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, join, doctrine-orm

I have 3 tables that I am trying to join together. I can join the "PurchaseOrderProductsStatus" table and the "Product" table but not the "PutAway" table, but I am not sure how to join in the other...

PurchaseOrderProductsStatus Table

```
id  | product_id | 
------------------
10  | 1          |
```

Product Table

```
id  | Name      | 
-----------------
1   | Acme      |
```

PutAway Table

```
id  | product_id | 
-----------------
100 | 1
```

In my Product Entity, I have a OneToMany relationship to the PutAway table. The PutAway table and the Product table are joined by the Product Id.

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="WIC\InventoryBundle\Entity\PutAway", mappedBy="product", fetch="EAGER")
 */
protected $putAway;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->putAway = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

In my PurchaseOrderProductsStatus custom query I am able to join in the product table, I am just not able to retrieve the collection of PutAway results. How would I do this?

Here is my query:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
->createQuery('
SELECT      p, pr
FROM        WIC\PurchaseOrderBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrderProductsStatus p
JOIN        p.product pr
WHERE       p.inventoryLocation = :id
AND         p.account = :account_id
GROUP By    p.product
')
->setParameter('id', $id)
->setParameter('account_id', $account_id);
```

Here is my twig template:

```
{% for action in productActions %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ action.product.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ action.product.sku }}</td>
        <td>{{ action.product.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ action.qty }}</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span2">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Purchase Order</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="span10">
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="put_away_{{ action.product.id }}">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Put Away Location</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Entered By</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {% for putAway in action.product.putAway %}
                            <tr class="info">
                                <td>{{ putAway.inventoryLocation.name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ putAway.qty }}</td>
                                <td>{{ putAway.created|date("m/d/Y") }}</td>
                                <td>{{ putAway.createdBy.firstName }} {{ putAway.createdBy.lastName }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I get the following error:

```
Key "putAway" for array with keys "id, archived_id_number, name, alternative_name, case_qty, description, sku, upc, unit_cost, retail_price, map_price, productWeightBig, productWeightSmall, productWeightUnit, productLength, productWidth, productHeight, productDimensionUnit, shippingWeightBig, shippingWeightSmall, shippingWeightUnitBig, shippingWeightUnitSmall, shippingLength, shippingWidth, shippingHeight, shippingDimensionUnit, path, created, updated, deletedAt" does not exist in
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is about reading the object that doctrine returns. You are doing a mixed query. Take a look at that: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Anyway, I would do it quite different, you should think from which object do the query: PurchaseOrderProductsStatus has one Product, that is allright, but then this join has multiple "PutAway". I would start by querying  the Put Away objects:

```
SELECT      pa, pr, pops
FROM        WIC\PurchaseOrderBundle\Entity\PutAway pa
LEFT JOIN        pa.product pr
LEFT JOIN        pr.PurchaseOrderProductsStatus pops
WHERE       p.inventoryLocation = :id AND p.account = :account_id
```

It is not exactly, play a little bit with it. The twig file will require modification.

Still, If the number of DB queries is reasonable, I wouldn't do it through a custom query, but just using standard Symfony, the TWIG that you wrote should just work if in your controller action you do:

```
$id= the id that you used on your query
$account= the object whose id you used on your query
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entities = $em->getRepository('WICPurchaseOrderBundle:PurchaseOrderProductsStatus')
->findAby(array('id'=>$id, 'account'=>$account));
```

The $entities should be the productActions in your twig. But just in the case the number of queries is reasonable.

Comment: The problem that I see with this is, Product entity has no association called PurchaseOrderProductsStatus so this left join wont work "LEFT JOIN pr.PurchaseOrderProductsStatus pops". Not sure how to get around this because this was the same issue I had in my own example. I cant join that 3rd table because the association fails.

Comment: Oh I see, then take a look at that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203027/is-this-possible-to-join-tables-in-doctrine-orm-without-using-relations. Anyway, I strongly recommend you to add the one to one relationship between Product and PurchaseOrderProductStatus, since you will be able to navigate through your objects in PHP (and would be the proper way). On the other hand, this kind of "plain" queries makes the object oriented programming useless.